# Ошибка при установке kivy, как можно исправить?

Tags: python, kivy

Пытался установить kivy через pip, действуя по инструкции.
Установил все зависимости, что были нужны, после чего прописал python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
Вышла ошибка:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k0xvxfsl\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k0xvxfsl\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g2oajloe'
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0xvxfsl\kivy\
    Complete output (394 lines):
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-l33qktf2\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-l33qktf2\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-n3qyfnjb'
           cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-l33qktf2\cython\
      Complete output (321 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      copying cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\BuildExecutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Cythonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Dependencies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Distutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Inline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\AnalysedTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Annotate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\AutoDocTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Builtin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CodeGeneration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CythonScope.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\DebugFlags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ExprNodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Interpreter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Lexicon.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\MemoryView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ModuleNode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Naming.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Optimize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\PyrexTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Pythran.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\StringEncoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TypeInference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TypeSlots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\UtilityCode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\UtilNodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Runtime
      copying Cython\Runtime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Runtime
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\extension.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\Cygdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\DebugWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\libcython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\libpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\TestLibCython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libcython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libpython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Actions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\DFA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex

      copying Cython\Plex\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Lexicons.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Machines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Regexps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Timing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Traditional.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Transitions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestCodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestCythonUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestJediTyper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestStringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\xmlrunner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestCyCache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestInline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestIpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestStripLiterals.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestBuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestCmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestFlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestGrammar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestMemView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestSignatureMatching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestUtilityLoad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestVisitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\compat3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\_looper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
      copying pyximport\pyxbuild.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
      copying pyximport\pyximport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
      copying pyximport\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes
      copying Cython\Includes\openmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\array.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytearray.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ceval.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\datetime.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\longintrepr.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pylifecycle.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pystate.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по логам, `kivy` пытается установить `Cython` - и у него не получается. Сначала установите `cython` командой:

```bsh
$ pip install cython
```

А потом уже ставьте `kivy`. Если установка `Cython` через `pip` не работает, попробуйте `easy_install` или другие системные средства.

Comment: Не сработало :(

Comment: @XXX больше подробностей: что не сработало? Какой вывод?

Comment: Всё тот-же. Спасибо за помощь в решении проблемы. Уже нашёл выход из ситуации.